# Python binary opposite operations

Tags: python

I have two numbers:

```
num1 = 1
num2 = 1
```

And then someone applied a secret operation on them:

```
mask = 2**8 -1
secret = (num1 << 8) | (num2 & mask)
>>> 257
```

How can I do the opposite of the secret operation? to get from `257` to `1 1`

Comment: You can't recover the original value of of `num2` if it is greater than 255, as the mask will erase the high bits in the original.

Comment: What have you tried / researched already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a standard way of encoding 2 small integers into a larger one

its 16bits of data  representing 2 8 bit integers

to get the first one (upper 8 bits) back you shift it the other way

```
256 >> 8
```

to get the lower 8 bits just and it with the original mask

```
256 & (2**8-1)
```

as mentioned in the comments most ints are int32 (32 bits, not 8) and you likely cannot recover num2 if its value was greater than 255, because 8 bits can only represent 0-255

as an aside I imagine most people would use (1<<8)-1  instead of 2**8-1

Comment: You shouldn't have done this guy's homework.  :-(